# How extract element from VectorType in LLVM?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am trying to compare two VectorType objects in LLVM and since VectorType does not have == operator I am trying to extract elements from my vector and compare them individually. I am working with FixedVectorType.
This is what I am trying to do.

```
if (VT->getElementType() == other.VT->getElementType() && VT->getNumElements() == other.VT->getNumElements()) {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < VT->getNumElements(); i++) {
            //extract elements and compare them
        }
      return true;
      }
```

I know that I need to use an instance of `ExtractElementInst`  class to extract element. I am not able to find any example of how to actually do that.

Comment: `ExtractElementInst` extracts an value from a composite value at runtime, what you want is probably [getElementType](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1VectorType.html#a12e23c3d619db313388fe11dc76eb23f), which extracts a type from a vector type at compile time.

Comment: getElementType() return a pointer to class Type. How can I get element value from Type*?

Comment: Basically, you have values at runtime. That's what running does — produce the values that the program computes. You can reason about values at compile time, and you can even do some partial evalutation. LLVM does that under the name "constant folding", optimisation sometimes does it. If you want to compare values at compile time you need to think very clearly about what part of your problem can be solved.

Comment: Where LLVM keeps element values after processing them?

Comment: FYI, if the vector element type is `icmp` or `fcmp` capable, you can also just `icmp` or `fcmp` the whole vector.